# How to find a function f from a list of input and outputs?

Tags: python, encryption, plot, screen-scraping

I'm scraping some data and have found that the values on a plot are created from a transformation from which I have x1,y1 and get x2,y2, it seems the mapping is one to one meaning that to generate y2 I only need y1 and to generate x2 I only need x1.

This is a sample of the points I have for x1 and x2:

```
x1 = 13.431585526415347, x2 = 138.2
x1 = 21.776351639704004, x2 = = 129.7
```

How can I find a function f so f(x1) = x2?

Comment: It could literally be anything. You show two points, so a line would work. With more points, higher order polynomial will always work. Given the absolute dearth of information, this question is impossible to answer.

Comment: Get a lot of data and plot it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have only 2 points, the simplest curve fitting 2 points is a straight line. The function that describes a straight line is `y=mx+c`, where `m` is the slope and `c` is the y-intercept.

So, to get a unique function for your 2 data points, we need to find the values of `m` and `c`. You can find them like this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x = np.array([13.431585526415347, 21.776351639704004])
y = np.array([138.2, 129.7])

def fit_func(x, m, c):
    return m*x + c

params = curve_fit(fit_func, x, y)

[m, c] = params[0]
print(m, c)
>>> -1.0186025449490008 151.88144719990683
```

So your function is: `f(x) = -1.0186025449490008*x + 151.88144719990683`

You can plot the function for some points (say, 1 to 10) if you want:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([m*x+c for x in range(10)], '*-')
```

[image]

---

Now, as Mad Physicist pointed out in his/her comment, if you give more data points, you can find that its not a straight line anymore - it can be anything.

So below is an example of fitting your 2 data points using the least squares polynomial fit:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

points = np.array([(13.431585526415347, 138.2), (21.776351639704004, 129.7),]) # enter more data points like this: (x1,x2)
# get x and y vectors
x = points[:,0]
y = points[:,1]

# calculate polynomial
z = np.polyfit(x, y, 3)
f = np.poly1d(z)

# calculate new x's and y's
x_new = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 50)
y_new = f(x_new)

plt.plot(x,y,'o', x_new, y_new)
plt.xlim([x[0]-1, x[-1] + 1 ])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Once you give more data points, you can try out different fitting functions and see which one fits your data best.